# Divs moving around when they should not?

Tags: html, css, division

I'm making a website for a project I'm involved in and I can't figure out why some of my divs are moving around when resizing the page while others aren't. I'm fairly new to both HTML and CSS so it might be something very basic but I can't figure out what it is. I think I've given all of my divs proper sizing, this is my code.

**CODE**

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.bakgrund {
  /*background-image: url("img/bakgrund.png");*/
  background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/1400x1400/000000/fff");
  height: 1400px;
  width: 1400px;
  position: absolute;
}

.logo {
  /*background-image: url("img/logo1.png");*/
  background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/821x1082/d415d4/fff");
  height: 1082px;
  width: 821px;
  top: -180px;
  right: 15%;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav {
  left: 670px;
  top: 450px;
  position: absolute;
}

.undertitel {
  right: 630px;
  top: 500px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bakgrund"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="index.html">Hem</a>
    <a href="kluringar.html">Kluringar</a>
  </div>
  <div class="undertitel">
    <p>"Många är kallade, få är utvalda"</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I open the HTML-document and resize the browser window both the div 'logo', 'undertitel' and 'bakgrund' moves with the page, while 'navbar' kind of stays in the same place, why is that?

Comment: I dont know what is your ultimate goal, but you are trying to set all position by using `position: absolute;` Which is probably the last thing to do.  SO you should check alignment with `display:flex;` container etc.

Comment: You should definitely tell us, what is your expected output.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! My goal is to position all the divs (logo, nav, undertitle and background) more or less right under each other, and so that they follow with the page when I'm resizing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

becouse u set `position:absolute` with `right:15%` it will adjust with screen width other div do not have `right` property

read for more info

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-understand-css-position-absolute-once-and-for-all-b71ca10cd3fd/

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to look through those pages!